# displaying sqlite records return error

Tags: php, sqlite

I have this code for displaying records from sqlite.

```
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open('database.sqlite');
    }
}
$db = new MyDB();
if(!$db){
echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} else {
    echo "Opened database successfully\n";
}


$sql =<<<EOF
  SELECT * from database_table_column;
EOF;

$ret = $db->query($sql);
while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
  echo "database id = ". $row['id'] . "\n";
  echo "database name = ". $row['database_name'] ."\n";
  echo "column name = ". $row['column_name'] ."\n";
}
echo "Operation done successfully\n";
$db->close();
```

and I got this following error (refer below)
1. Warning: SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, no such table: database_table_column
2. Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchArray() on a non-object

I'm sure I have database.sqlite file and created a database_table_column table with id column, database_name column and column_name column but why doesnt work? any ideas, suggestions, recommendations and help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: $sql = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM database_table_column');

Comment: same error @anantkumarsingh

Comment: i changed it try with that

Comment: Try $sql = $db->prepare('SELECT* FROM database_table_column');$result =$sql->execute();
var_dump($result->fetchArray());

Comment: same error. why is that the error is telling me that there is no such table: database_table_column when I have one? im sure i have it ang im looking on it right now using a third party sqlite browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74242/discussion-between-anant-kumar-singh-and-code-demon).